# Access SObject and SOBjects fields labels

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Is there a way to access SObject  labels and SObject fields labels directly from lightning ?

Today we recreate custom labels and call them as {!$Label.c.SomeCustomLabel}

I'd really like do to the same to refer SObject fields without doing server calls to call metadata apis via Apex

Something like {!$Label.c.CustomObject__c.Field__c} .. do someone know a way ?
If there isn't dear SalesForce people would you think about it ?

Thanks !

nb: for UI reasons we can not use force:inputField

Comment: No other known way till now. You have to use custom labels only. Create a custom label for field's label. Or, if you have a lot, better retrieve via Apex.

Comment: I need this feature also, and this is not available these days, so I have created an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNLeQAM) - please vote for it so Salesforce would take into consideration